# How to autoselect option depending on input's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html-select

I need select's option to be actually selected on document ready depending on an input's value.

Example:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="1">myVal1</option>
<option value="2">myVal2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myId" value="2">
```

For example, we've got a predefined value '2' of the input on page load. I need select-box to be auto-selected with it's option having the same value as input 'myId'. I mean 'mayVal1' must be selected.

When input has no value select must behave as default.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework? Or you're looking at how to do this using plain javascript

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I'm using jquery

Comment: @AndreasWong, please edit the title and possibly the post itself to add whether you'd prefer or allow answers that use jQuery. The tag is a good place to start but it's good to be clear for others searching for similar solutions.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "select must behave as default" do you mean it should behave as it would given the above markup and without the value being set deliberately?

Comment: It's not even my question o_O @jpierson

Comment: Sorry AndreasWong, I should have directed my suggestion to @IgorYakushchenko, the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mention of "on document ready" sort of suggests that you might be using jQuery, with that assumption made (albeit perhaps erroneously), I offer you this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        var theValue = $('#myId').val();
        $('option[value=' + theValue + ']')
            .attr('selected',true);
    });
```

[With a demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mRE9Y/).

---

**Edited** in response to OP's question:

> How do I compare option's value to very first word in the input's value? I mean if I have option value 'hello' and input value 'hello world' script have to select option containing 'hello' in its value.

Right, given the disparity between your posted example and your question, I'm going to try to address both of the possibilities.

First, to select an `option` based on its **text** component (in your above code, the 'myVal1','myVal2' bits):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('form:eq(0)').submit(
            function() {
                var theValue = $('#myId').val().split(" ",1);
                $('option:contains(' + theValue + ')').attr('selected', true);
                return false;
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mRE9Y/1/): note that the text component of the `option` element does *not* represent the *value* of the `option` element.

Secondly, if you want to link the first part of the value entered into the `myId` input element to the *value* of the `select`/`option` element(s):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('form:eq(0)').submit(
            function() {
                var theValue = $('#myId').val().split(" ",1);
                $('option[value=' + theValue + ']').attr('selected', true);
                return false;
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mRE9Y/2/).

These demos *could* work with [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), or equivalent actions/events, but [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) seemed the better choice.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. 10x a lot

Comment: @gov it's just a knack... =) That and, I think, because of the load-balancing aspect of the SO set-up. So we don't all see the same questions at the same time; so I might've caught this question a couple of minutes ahead of you.

Comment: one more question please. How do I compare option's value to very first word in the input's value? I mean if I have option value 'hello' and input value 'hello world' script have to select option containig 'hello' in it's value. Thanks!

Comment: @Igor, StackOverflow is better suited to asking precise and narrow questions which could have more broad applicability outside of your personal scenario. If you have multiple questions I would recommend posting those as separate questions otherwise if you're looking for a more interactive and flexible discussion perhaps chat or a different platform would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

something like below should work///

```
<select>
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(
    var inputValue = $('#id').val();
    $('select').val('1'); // selects "Two"
    $('select').val(inputValue); // also selects "Two"

});
```

Comment: if you mutliple select boxes give a id <select id="selectBox">

Answer (score 1):

in vanilla JS:

```
var listener = function(ev){
var input = document.getElementById('myId');
for(var i = 0, elems = document.getElementById('mySelect'), l = elems.length; i < l; i++)
    elems[i].selected = elems[i].value == input.value;    
}
listener();
document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('change', listener, false);
```

with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myId').change(function(){
       $('#mySelect option').removeAttr('selected').filter('[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('selected', true);
    }).change()
})
```

Comment: why do we need change ??? the text box is alread populated on load , all you need to do is read that set it...

Comment: updated the code. I think it's a good idea to trigger it on change as well, no?

Comment: will the above code sets the select box on load???if so thats fine.it takes care of both scenarios like user change the text box value later

Comment: yes, so long as you enter the code in a window.onload function. Are you using jQuery or not, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#mySelect').val('2').change();`

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?