# Select first option that is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how to `autoselect` in a `selectbox`? I want to do is even though there is a `blank option` the selectbox will still show the option that has a value on it.

Does anyone know how to do it in jquery?

html code:

```
<select name="name">
<option></option>
<option>Mark</option>
</select>

<select name="age">
<option></option>
<option>16</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can put the option with a value before the one with no value

Comment: this may help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354455/how-to-autoselect-option-depending-on-inputs-value

Comment: Just set `selected` on the selected one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this help you :

**HTML:**

```
<select name="name">
<option></option>
<option>Mark</option>
</select>

<select name="age" id='some'>
<option></option>
<option>16</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$($('#some').children()[1]).attr('selected',true)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one empty `option`, and there is no order, this is the best solution I think:
 
 **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MAYRV/1/)**

What we've done here is, checking every `selectbox` by a [each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/%E2%80%8E) loop:

```
 $('select').each(function()
 {

 });
```

And then inside the loop we [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) option which is [not empty](http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/):

```
$(this).find('option:not(:empty)').first()
```

And make it selected by [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(this).find('option:not(:empty)').first().prop('selected',true);
```

So the whole jQuery and Html will be:

**jQuery**

```
  $('select').each(function()
  {
        $(this).find('option:not(:empty)').first().prop('selected',true);
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="name">
    <option></option>
    <option>Mark</option>
</select>
<select name="age">
    <option></option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option></option>
    <option>55</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this to all `select` boxes on the page, use this:

```
$(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
        $(this).find('option').not(':empty()').first().attr('selected', true);
    })
});
```

It grabs each `select`, finds the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) `option` that is [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) (read: has text inside it) and [sets the `selected` attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HFUP/).

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript to do this, if you want to select (Mark) for example, do it like this

```
<select name="name">
<option></option>
<option selected>Mark</option>
</select>
```

and in XHTML:

```
<select name="name">
<option></option>
<option selected="selected">Mark</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option likes this:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

then :empty wil not work, instead use:

```
$(this).find('option').filter((i, el) => el.value.length > 0).first().prop('selected',true)
```